# Twig error if element not existing

Tags: twig, silex

I'm using Silex with Twig, and I'm trying to find the occurrence of a key.

Since the key doesn't always exist, method 1 will fail with an exception. Method 2 on the other hand works without errors, however I would like to avoid the extra *for* and *if* conditions.

Can this be done?

**Method 1:**

```
{% if app.session.get('shop').modules.promotion %}
    exists
{% endif %}
```

**Method 2:**

```
{% if app.session.get('shop').modules is not empty %}
    {% for id, config in app.session.get('shop').modules %}
        {% if id == 'promotion' %}
            exists
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is defined`.

```
{% if app.session.get('shop').modules.promotion is defined %}
    exists
{% endif %}
```

More info about `defined` can be found here:
[Twig: Defined documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/defined.html)